# The specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities. using JSON, KendoUI, AJAX

Tags: ajax, json, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

Hi everyone thanks for the time to help me out.

I'm testing KendoUI and I'm try to binding a Grid using AJAX but i get the error

```
The specified type member 'getFullName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

My Models looks like this

**Proyectos Model**

```
public class Proyecto
{

    [Required]
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Num. Proyecto")]
    public virtual String ProyectoID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "ID Usuario")]
    public virtual int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Fecha De Inicio")]
    public virtual DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Fecha de Fin")]
    public virtual DateTime FechaFin { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descripcion")]
    public virtual String Descripcion { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public virtual int StatusID { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Comentario> Comentarios { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Abono> Abonos{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cargo> Cargos{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Status> Status { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

}
```

**Usuario Model**

```
    public class Usuario
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public virtual int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Usuario")]
    public virtual String UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public virtual String Password{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    public virtual String Nombre { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Apellidos")]
    public virtual String Apellidos{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public virtual String Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nivel")]
    public virtual int Nivel { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Proyecto> Proyectos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comentario> Comentarios { get; set; }

    [Display (Name="Responsable")]
    public virtual string getFullName
    {
        get {
            return Nombre + " " + Apellidos;
        }

    }

}
```

In the Proyecto Controller i have this method (where the error happens)

```
 public ActionResult Proyectos_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var proyectos = from e in db.Proyectos.Include(c => c.Usuario) select e;


        DataSourceResult result = proyectos.ToDataSourceResult(request, o => new
        {
            ProyectoID = o.ProyectoID,
            OCCliente = o.OCCliente,
            FullName = o.Usuario.getFullName,
            Descripcion = o.Descripcion
        });



        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and finally this is my View

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<NTSMvc.Models.Proyecto>()
                         .Name("Grid")
                         .Columns(columns =>
                             {
                                 columns.Bound(p => p.ProyectoID).Filterable(true).Groupable(true);
                                 columns.Bound(p => p.OCCliente);
                                 columns.Bound(p => p.Usuario.getFullName);
                                 columns.Bound(p => p.Descripcion);
                             })
                             .DataSource( datasource => datasource
                                 .Ajax()
                                 .Read(read => read.Action("Proyectos_Read","Proyectos"))
                                 .PageSize(5)
                             )
                             .Filterable() 
                             .Groupable()                               
                             .Pageable()                                   
                     )
```

How i need to change my linq query or my model to get the full name in the grid

Thanks again for the time.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom logic inside virtual string property called **getFullName** of your ViewModel could not be translated to the SQL syntax.

I would suggest you to remove that property and again use the two regular properties **Nombre** ,**Apellidos**. I assume  you want to create a column which is a concatenation of these properties. If so you can create a template column and the following template:

```
Html.Kendo().Grid...
...
Columns(cols=>{
    cols.Template(@<text></text>).Title("Full Name").ClientTemplate("#: Nombre # #: Apellidos #")
})
```

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: Yes i want to display in a column the full Name I'll try this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can try change the "result" definition to the following

```
DataSourceResult result = proyectos.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x).ToDataSourceResult(request, o => new
        {
            ProyectoID = o.ProyectoID,
            OCCliente = o.OCCliente,
            FullName = o.Usuario.getFullName,
            Descripcion = o.Descripcion
        });
```

Comment: This does work - yet in a grid with over 300k entries, the lazyload does not function and it takes about 10 seconds to load the grid